# Multipart body length limit 16384

Tags: c#, android, web, webservice, xamarin

Se que existe mucha informacion sobre este error en la web, he tratado muchisimas y nada funciona:

Este es el codigo en el web api, como se ve tengo, en teoria, los codigos para evitar ese error

```
    [HttpPost]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]     
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 100_000_000)]
```

Como se puede ver he usado todas o casi todas las opciones que dicen y nada

```
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]     
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 100_000_000)]
```

En el web.config tengo:

```
        <httpRuntime .. maxRequestLength="..." />
        </system.web>   
        <system.webServer>          
        <security>
        <requestFiltering>                  
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
        </requestFiltering>             
        </security>             
        </system.webServer>
```

y nada.
Estoy usando XAMARIN VS 2022 y el api lo ejecuto despues de tomar la foto con:

```
        var file = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
        if (file == null) return;                        
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StreamContent(await file.OpenReadAsync()), "file", file.FileName);          
        string url = "https://10.0.2.2:7254/Api/getData";
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url,content);
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado reiniciar el IIS?